# Russian Language encoded when using imap_fetch from gmail

Tags: php, encoding, imap

Im reading a log file pasted into the body of an email, some are in various different languages and all language characters seem to display correctly except for Russian.

Here is an example of what the Russian says in the log file:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
>
> в

From what I have read I need to specify decoding or encoding something on the lines of mb_encoding (UTF-8) but I am a bit lost on how to actual structure it without affecting code that isnt russian. But when echoed out it gets converted to this:

> Ð¡ÑÑ‹Ð»ÐºÐ° Ð½Ð° Ð¾Ð±ÑŠÐµÐºÑ‚ Ð½Ðµ ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ñ‹Ð²Ð°ÐµÑ‚ Ð½Ð° ÑÐºÐ·ÐµÐ¼Ð¿Ð»ÑÑ€ Ð¾Ð±ÑŠÐµÐºÑ‚Ð°.
> Ð²

Here is the code im using already, I am a php beginner and some of this isnt my code, I have edited to suit but not 100% what everything is doing:

```
$mailbox = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mailboxPassword = "xxx";

$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX",
                     $mailbox, $mailboxPassword);

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$subject = mb_decode_mimeheader(str_replace('_', ' ', $subject));

$body = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1);
$body = base64_decode($body);

echo $body;
```

Once I `echo` out body it converts from Russian into that encoding, any pointers on similar code I can dissect to learn how to fix this?

Please bear in mind there is numerous languages been read from the email, for the most part its just a few snippets and the rest is basic logging but what I am worried about is if I set a new decode that it will mess up other language characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its large adoption, email is still tricky to work with. If your IMAP client has a limited set of requirements, your job will be easy. Otherwise, for truly a general-purpose GMail client, there's no silver bullet and you have to un understand how email wokrs: SMTP, MIME and finally IMAP.

Basic MIME knowledge is absolutely needed, and I won't paste the whole wikipedia article, but you should really [read it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) and understand how it works. IMAP is somewhat easier to understand.

Usually, email messages contains either a single *text/plain* body, or a *multipart/alternative* body with both a *text/plain* and a *text/html* part. But, you know, there are attachments, so you can also likely find a *multipart/mixed* and it can really contain anything, and if it's binary content you should treat it differently than text. There are two headers (which you can find in the *global* message or in part inside a multipart envelope) somewhat involved in charset issues: *Content-Type* and *Content-Transfer-Encoding*.

From your code, we must assume that you are only interested in textual *parts* base64-encoded. Once you have decoded them, they are a sequence of byte representing text in the charset specified by the sender in the *Content-Type* header, which is non-ASCII here and thus looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Note that *charset* may be *utf8* or really any other you can think of, you have to check this in your program. You job is transcoding this piece of input in the output charset of your HTML page. If your page does not use a Unicode encoding (like UTF-8), chances are that you can't even be able to show the message correctly, and '?' will be printed instead of missing characters. Since you require your application to be used worldwide (not just in Russia), and since it's anyway good practice, you should use UTF-8 in your HTML responses, and thus when you want to echo the message body:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding(imap_base64($body), "UTF-8", $input_charset);
```

where `$input_charset` is the one found in the *Content-Type* header for the processed part. For the subject line, you should use [`imap_mime_header_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php), which returns an array of tuples (binary string, charset) which you have to output in the same manner as above.

**TL;DR**

The bytes in the UTF-8 encoded input text map quite nicely to the output if we assume it's [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoded (maybe you didn't copy some non printable ones). This means that the input is UTF-8, but the browser thinks the page is Windows-1252. Likely this is the default browser behavior for your locale, and you can easily correct it by sending the appropriate header before any other input:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

This should be enough to solve *this* issue, but will also likely cause problem with non-ASCII characters in string literals and the database (if any). If you want a multilingual application, Unicode is the way, but you have to transcode your database and your PHP files from CP-1252 to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i tried accessing the emails charset via this:
$headers1 = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $val);

But even the Russian emails all show as UTF-8 so i have no idea how to find out which ones i have to do the mb_convert_encoding on

Comment: @user1547410 I cannot understand what you said, please rephrase it. Also, if the sender program is under you control, you can check its side to know the encoding of the message

Comment: Basically i was trying to find the correct value for $input_charset. I thought i might find it in imap_fetchstructure but everything returns saying its UTF-8.

I dont have control over the program thats sending the original email

Comment: @user1547410 Can you please paste the whole header? If the string is binary utf8 and your output page also is utf8, there will be no problem

Comment: @user1547410 I did some test. The faul is your HTML, because it's using some 8-bit character encoding (likely a windows code page or some ISO-8859 variant). This is unsuitable for a multilingual application because Unicode characters can't be represented with a limited charset. You have to switch your entire frontend encoding

Comment: You have no idea how helpful you have been, this is all it took in the header to fix it <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 but i have not worked with multilingual before and this has never been an issue, super and thanks Mate